# Angular2 Observables best practice

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

let's say I have a component which has a child component. For example this simple calendar:
[image]

Here is its template:

```
<month-board [current-month]="currentMonth$"></month-board>
<button (click)="decrement()">Prev</button>
<button (click)="increment()">Next</button>
```

when the buttons are clicked the `month-board` which subscribed to `currentMonth$` is subscribed is changing the displayed month.

`currentMonth$` type is `Observable<Moment>`.
My question is: is it a good practice to pass Observables to child components in Angular2? is there any better way to do this?

Parent full code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'month-view',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/month-view/month-view.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/components/month-view/month-view.css'],
  directives: [MonthBoard],
})

export class MonthView {
  currentMonth: Moment = moment();
  currentMonth$: Observable<Moment>;
  currentMonthObserver: Observer<Moment>;
  decrement: Function;
  increment: Function;

  constructor() {
    this.currentMonth$ = Observable.create((observer: Observer<Moment>) => {
      this.currentMonthObserver = observer;
    });


    const decrementCounter$: Observable<Function> = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.decrement = () => {
        observer.next();
      };
    });

    const incrementCounter$: Observable<Function> = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.increment = () => {
        observer.next();
      };
    });

    this.currentMonth$.subscribe();

    Observable
      .merge(
        decrementCounter$.map(() => - 1),
        incrementCounter$.map(() => + 1)
      )
      .startWith(0)
      .scan((currentCount: number, value: number) => currentCount + value)
      .subscribe((count: number) => {
        this.currentMonthObserver.next(this.currentMonth.clone().add(count, 'M'));
      });
  }
}
```

Child full code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'month-board',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/month-board/month-board.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/components/month-board/month-board.css'],
  directives: [DayCell]
})
export class MonthBoard implements OnInit{
  @Input('current-month') currentMonth: Observable<Moment>;
  weeks: Moment[][];

  constructor(private calendarHelper: CalendarHelper) {
    this.weeks = this.calendarHelper.getMonthWeeks();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentMonth.subscribe((month: Moment) => {
      this.weeks = this.calendarHelper.getMonthWeeks(month);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way, the other way is with @input.  It's very easy to pass values from parent to child with it.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

I don't think it's necessarily bad to pass observables that way to your child component.  For example I have a service that uses an observable that my whole application uses to watch for logged in events.  But for a Calendar you might find yourself wanting to pass different values in different places on the same observable.  If you do that you can always make another observable.  Or manipulate it in different ways for each component.

But for readability I would definitely just use @input, that way I only have to go to the parent component to figure out what I am passing around.

Comment: The observable is passed to the child component through @input. Please see the full code. It would be nice if you can give a better suggestion for implementation.

Comment: You don't have to make your input an observable is what I was trying to say.  I'll give an example when I have some more time.  Angular2 will automatically update the data-bound property.  So making an observable is redundant.  If the value changes in the parent component, the value will change for your child component as well.